# Как создать шаблон для элемента XAML, для многократного использования (в UWP приложении на C#)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

То есть в моём приложении нужно сделать эдакую ленту, в которой будет множество элементов со структурой:

```
Grid>Text, Image, Text /
```

Так вот, я душой понимаю что должен быть способ как-то создать этот шаблон, и потом в коде C# его использовать.

Но в гугле ничего найти не могу, а сам не допираю. Попытался создать страницу с этим шаблончиком, и потом в коде страницы с лентой создавать каждый раз новый экземпляр страницы с шаблончиком и оттуда брать сетку. Но при попытке добавить сетку к дочерним элементам StackPanel'a ловлю ошибку "Element is already child of another element", что вполне предсказуемо и закономерно, да и сам мой путь какой-то стрёмный.

Как это делать правильно?

Comment: Подозреваю что мой вопрос может показаться кому-то тупым, но я правда зашёл в тупик и не могу представить что делать.

Comment: Вместо `<br>` можно просто два переноса строки ставить, чтобы разбить параграф.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужен список из кучи однотипных элементов и для этих элементов хотите шаблон, то это называется `DataTemplate` для `ListView` (или `GridView`).

Если вы хотите какой-то контрол несколько раз использовать, то это называется `UserControl`. 
Уточните, что хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Ууу, спасибо! Точно то что нужно.